# Multiple condition on single column to return data into multiple columns

Tags: sql

I have a Query, retrieving around 60+ columns, where column name 'qualification' (sslc, hsc, diploma) and their respective marks ('Sslc marks', 'Hsc Marks Percentage', 'diploma') have retrieved in different rows for each candidate.

for eg. Candidate 'X' has 'hsc' qualification, then Candidate 'x' will be retrieving in two rows where sslc marks as one column and hsc marks percentage in another column

But need the data to be retrieve as, each candidate against their respective qualification marks in the same row

[Screenshot of csv file where data retrieved from query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAo3o.png)

[The Model output for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxe5a.png)`

Existing Query for the reference -

```
select 
pd.registration_no as "REGISTRATION NUMBER",
(case when edu.education_level_category_id='1' then 'sslc'
      when edu.education_level_category_id='2' then 'hsc' 
      when edu.education_level_category_id='3' then 'diploma' end )"QUALIFICATION",
(CASE WHEN qm.education_level_id='1' THEN qm.aggregate_percentage          
            END ) "SSLC MARKS",
(CASE WHEN qm.education_level_id='2' THEN qm.aggregate_percentage             
            END ) "HSC MARKS PERCENTAGE",
pd.applicant_cred_id as "APP CRED ID",
(CASE WHEN qm.education_level_id='1' THEN qm.certificate_number            
            END ) "SSLC SNO",
(CASE WHEN qm.education_level_id='3' THEN qm.aggregate_percentage             
            END ) "DIPLOMA",
            



from 
personal_details pd,
additional_details ad,
rps_exam_result res,
applicant_hallticket ah,
phase2_admit_card admit,
caste_category_master caste,
education_level_category edu,
qualification_master qm



where ad.applicant_cred_id=pd.applicant_cred_id
and
ah.applicant_cred_id=pd.applicant_cred_id
and
res.fk_hall_ticket_number=ah.hallticket_number
and
admit.applicant_credential_id=ad.applicant_cred_id
and 
pd.applicant_cred_id=admit.applicant_credential_id
and
caste.category_id=pd.category_id
and
pd.education_level_category_id=edu.education_level_category_id
and
qm.applicant_cred_id=pd.applicant_cred_id
and
ad.applicant_cred_id=qm.applicant_cred_id



group by
pd.registration_no, 
pd.date_of_birth,
pd.name,
pd.father_name,
pd.mother_name, 
pd.photo_identity_card_number,
pd.emailid_primary,
pd.applicant_cred_id,
pd.age_relaxation,
pd.validity_of_community_certificate,
pd.date_of_issue_community_certificate,
pd.photo_path,
pd.signature_path,
pd.community_certificate_path,
pd.photo_identity_path,
pd.photo_path,
ad.ncc_certificate_type,
ad.ncc_certificate_path,
res.sectioni_marks,
res.sectionii_marks,
res.sectioniii_marks,
res.sectioniv_marks,
res.sectionv_marks,
res.marks_relaxation_availed,
ah.hallticket_number,
admit.phase2_asc,
admit.phase2_test_date,
admit.chest_no,
admit.applicant_phase2_regno,
caste.category_long_code,
edu.education_level_category_id,
qm.aggregate_percentage,
qm.marksheet_path,
qm.certificate_number,
qm.date_of_issue_marksheet,
qm.education_level_id


order by pd.registration_no limit 5
```

Comment: Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: Edit tags to show database platform.